# Read output from command line

Tags: php, windows, terminal, stdout

How I can open a terminal(command line, cmd), write command (example: dir) and get output and echo in new command line(terminal, cmd). In live time. I mean finish "echo"ing after closing 1 terminal which getting output of commands. I have surfed and don't find anything. This script is in WINDOWS 10

Comment: `system('dir');` ?

Comment: @AbraCadaver No sir. I have to run terminal and i will enter commands then i wll get output of commands. not only 1 command script should keep-alived. Exit script after closing terminal